# How to implement associations with one class in the middle - Person, owns, Car

Tags: java, associations

I have a problem with the following class diagram.
https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-3b1169-1545377131.png.html

In exercises we had association between 2 classes. For example Person --- Residence with different multiplicities, unidirectional and without directions and so on. This image was displayed as last in our lecture. And the image says like "With this (arrow) the implementation is clear". But for me it isn't that trivial. We had never an example of such an implementation before. The class "owns" in the middle makes it difficult for me.

I tried to implement it but my implementation doesn't make sense. I would be able to implement it if the class "owns" wouldn't be there. I would use a container type (Linked List) in Person for multiple cars. And In Car for multiple persons. For each class a getter method (Collection) and add/remove methods (bidirectional). And I would provide 2 different Car constructors. Car(String color, int speed, Person owner) and Car(String color, int speed, LinkedList owners. In the first I would add the Person to the LinkedList and in the second I would add all elements of the LinkedList owners to the LinkedList of the object. And some more trivial code. But for this image above I have no idea and hope you can help me.

PS: I would also be happy if you could send me a link where implementations of  association, composition, generalization and UML class diagrams are explained. I think that our lectures aren't really informative and don't explain things in detail. :(

Comment: Let me explain the problem. To create a Car I need at least 1 owns (ownership object with Date, Person, Car). And to create 1 owns I need 1 car. But how should I put a Car obj. in it's constructor if the same Car obj. needs a owns obj to be created. That's my problem :(

Comment: I think you are confusing association with composition. You don't need a Car or Owns to create a Person (same goes for car). They are separate class that don't need each other to exist. Association only shows how the two classes are associated.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I didn't knew the names of the concepts. Now things start to make sense. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically "owns" class is used to hold data that do not belong to either Person or Car, instead it belongs to the relationship between the classes (in this case datePurchased).

This is useful when designing how your data are saved in the database.
In this case "owns" will contain the datePurchased data. In actual implementation it will also needs the primary key of Person and Car.
So for example you want search a certain Person's Car, you will search it from the "Owns" table using the Person's name (assuming it is unique and used as primary ID).

So with this design your Person and Car class will not contain any Collection or any data about each other, instead the association data between Person and Car is stored in Owns class.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your response. I thought the diagrams tells me that a Car obj. needs at least 1 owns obj. Now things are clearer.

Comment: The constructor of both Person and Car doesn't contain anything about each other, instead you create another class "owns" to show the association between the two. For example a person buys a car, what happens is you get the person's primary key and the car's primary key then use it to create a new owns.